# If conditional independence and dependence imply each other, what will happen?

Tags: probability

Three random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$.

1. if the following two  imply each other

   - $X$ and $Y$ being independent,
   - $X$ and $Y$ being conditionally independent on $Z$,

   then what (interesting) conclusions can you draw? For example,

   - are $(X,Y)$ and $Z$  independent?
2. if the following two  imply each other

   - $X$ and $Y$ being independent,
   - $X$ and $Y$ being conditionally independent on **an arbitrary random variable**

   then what (interesting) conclusions can you draw?

Thanks!

Comment: What does 'X and Y being conditionally independent on Z imply each other' mean?

Comment: Does my edit make it clear?

Comment: Still not a question. What are the hypotheses, what is the (desired) conclusion?

Comment: @Did: Got it now? If it were you, how would you rephrase my question?

Comment: Note that saying '"$X$ and $Y$ are independent" and "$X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent on $Z$" imply each other"' is equivalent to saying 'either "$X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent on $Z$" or "$X$ and $Y$ are not independent, and $X$ and $Y$ are not conditionally independent on $Z$" imply each other"'.

Comment: Reformulation still opaque. Your hypothesis is a general implication? If the implication holds you have no hypothesis at all, if it does not you can prove anything assuming it.

Comment: @Did: My condition is an implication. How do you say it if it were you? By "general" implication, you mean the implication is always true?

Comment: If your hypothesis is an implication, indeed you are assuming that the implication holds always. Thus, chaos.

Comment: @DId: My hypothesis is an implication,  meaning let's consider those cases when the implication is true, and ignore other cases when it is not,  instead of meaning  I claim that the implication is true in any case.